# openssl can be found by yum but can't be found by pkg-config

Tags: centos, yum

I found openssl is already installed on my server

```
# yum list installed | grep openssl
openssl.x86_64                          1:1.0.2k-26.el7_9        @updates
openssl-libs.x86_64                     1:1.0.2k-26.el7_9        @updates
```

However, it couldn't be found by pkg-config

```
# pkg-config --libs --cflags openssl
Package openssl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `openssl.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'openssl' found
```

I want to know what's wrong and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `pkg-config` is used for develop libraries and have (directly) nothing to do with system packages, installed in the OS.

Comment: do you mean I have to install something like `openssl-devel`?

Comment: AFAIK - yes, this util search for dev libraries and it is mostly in use when you compile something

Comment: I tried, and it works now, thank you